# Find the Cartesian equation for the curve?

Tags: calculus

$r = \cot(\theta)\cos(\theta)$

My answer keeps coming out to $r=\csc(\theta)$, however I don't believe that is right.

I know I am supposed to multiply by $r$, but does that make it: $r^2= r\cot^2(\theta) + r\cos^2(\theta)$?

or $r^2= r\cot^2(\theta)\cdot r\cos^2(\theta)$?

Comment: If $r=\cot(\theta)\cos(\theta)$, then $$r=\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\cdot\cos(\theta)=\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{ \sin(\theta)}=\frac{1-\sin^2(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\csc(\theta)-\sin(\theta)$$Also, If you multiply by $r$ you get $r^2=r\cot(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $r^2\sin\theta$ and you should be able to replace everything in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

One may write
$$
r=\frac{\cos \theta }{\sin \theta}\cdot\cos \theta=\frac1r\cdot\frac{r\cos \theta }{r\sin \theta}\cdot r\cos \theta
$$ that is
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot \frac{x}{y}\cdot x.
$$ then one may conclude.

Answer (score 1):

$$ r=\csc\theta\cos\theta=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\cdot\cos\theta$$

Multiply both sides by $r^2\sin\theta$ to obtain

$$ r^2\cdot r\sin\theta= r^2\cos^2\theta$$

which is

$$ (x^2+y^2)y=x^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

$r = \cot(\theta)\cos(\theta)=\cfrac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}\cos \theta$

$x=r\cos \theta ~\& ~y=r\sin \theta\implies x^2+y^2=r^2$

Putting values above we have,

$r=\cfrac{\cfrac{x}{r}}{\cfrac{y}{r}}\cfrac{x}{r}=\cfrac{x^2}{yr}$

$\implies  r^2y=x^2\implies(x^2+y^2)y=x^2$